# How to navigate on table using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, keyboard

I have a table:

```
<table border="1" width="500">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>            
    <th>SurName</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Sum</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>White</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class='hov'>20.00</td>
    <td class='hov'>20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Anton</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td class='hov'>50.00</td>
    <td class='hov'>50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Boris</td>
    <td>Crane</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td class='hov'>80.00</td>
    <td class='hov'>80.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Angel</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td class='hov'>60.00</td>
    <td class='hov'>60.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Manny</td>
   <td>Red</td>
   <td>90</td>
   <td class='hov'>10.00</td>
   <td class='hov'>10.00</td>
</tr>
```

I need to navigate on table only for `class=hov` and need to work all four keys down, up, left, right And I can edit this field and after press Enter need to key down.

This is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ebyvalkevich/hs03ukzo/9/

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code you have written to attempt to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to keypress event and detect if arrow key was pressed like :

```
 $(window).on('keypress', function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == '37') {
         //do some stuff here}
 }


left = 37 up = 38 right = 39 down = 40
```

and inside such blocks you describe your logic.

UPD: Focus cell

For this purpose u can use `$('#yourCellId').focus()`

Comment: thank you but I have a problem how to move the cursor one cell

Comment: Do you mean focus cell ?

Comment: focus cell need to edit and hover cell need to see where is focus

Comment: And I didn't get your last comment. What does it mean "hover cell need to see where is focus?"

Comment: hover it is in my example blue outline and when I navigate keyboard so I see outline on cell and set focus to this cell

Comment: in my example there are to columns sum and total and I need to navigate only for these cells up down right left